# Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [5:45]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
select 
usertype,
concat(start_station_name,"to", end_station_name) AS route,
COUNT(*) as num_trips,
round(avg(cast(tripduration as int64)/60,2) AS duration
from 'bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips'
group by 
start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
order by
num_trips DESC
limit 10
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to close the parenthesis for the AVG function:

```
round(avg(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration f
```

See the bracket at the end of `/60)`